# How often does Basil change his selection?

Tags: spiral-knights

I am in quest of a certain 5-star recipe for which Basil is the only vendor (yes, I know I *could* just get it at the Auction House, but Basil is a lot cheaper).  Since he's only found in the Clockworks, and only sells 5-star recipes in Tier 3, it is not easy to get to him when he might have my recipe.

I'd rather not waste energy getting to him to check whether he has my recipe yet if his selection hasn't changed.  How often does Basil get different supplies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this post](http://forums.spiralknights.com/en/node/26331).

This guy's comment is useful:

> There are 109 five star equippable items in the game, not counting trinkets. Basil can have a recipe for nearly any of them, though there are a few that he doesn't carry. If he has five five star items in a typical tier 3 run, then your odds of finding the item you're looking for are around 5%. That's why it takes a while to find it.
>
> Basil rerolls what he has every time you get there in a separate group. You could write down what he has from one run to the next if you like. It's mostly different stuff each time, even if it's not the item you're after. If you're in a hurry, try the auction house.